# Java.Robot is kinda slow, can it be sped up? Or is there a better alternative?

Tags: java, performance, awtrobot

So I've got a simple bot that moves the mouse then clicks, that's all;

```
r.mouseMove(/*position*/);
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);              
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Ultra simple.
It ought to be really quick but i takes ages to move and click. It seems fast but when the task i have for it accelerates the bot can't keep up.
Can the Robot be improved?
Should i try Something else?
I read something about creating a new thread for it, what's that mean?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: The robot has a delay of around 50ms I *think* (will look it up). In any case, it is not guaranteed to be precise or consistent. Running the same program over and over can yield different timings.

Comment: Faster? You could write code that directly communicates with the OS via JNA or JNI, but that would be much more involved.

Comment: Alright, I can't find anything specific but I found my test program of trying to make robot play a sidescroller (predetermined) level by scripting the keyboard actions. When required to make subsequent calls without delay there seems to be an OS-dependent delay of O(10) ms or less.